How to add a cell reference to Date Filter in Excel Pivot Tables
I have a date in cell C3, I want the Pivot table to only show expenses from that day. I tried entering the cell reference in this field to create a custom filter but it does not work. I also tried using Date function with Year, Month and Day functions, but that didn't work either.
Is there any way to create custom formulas (like we do in conditional formatting) for date filters in Excel Pivot Tables?


have you tried clicking each of the buttons in the dialog?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Pivot tables are either filtered by selecting a value in the column headings or using slicers.
If you have a date field in the pivot table, I suggest you add a timeline slicer to the pivot table, set it to Days as the unit and select the day.

That way, you do not have to re-invent the wheel.
For more information about timeline filters, see this Microsoft article Create a PivotTable timeline to filter dates

If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

So Pivot Table date filters give you and option to create a custom filter. I want to do this, 'Equals' = C3
So anytime I change the date in C3, the Pivot automatically changes to filter out that date's data. Say I want to put a specific date from the past year, looking for a transaction, I don't want to manually enter the date filter, then search or select that date (in 5 pivots I have in this dashboard). I want to edit the date in C3 cell and maybe add a refresh button with macro to refresh all pivots.

The date filter in your screenshot cannot reference a cell in the worksheet. That is why we use timeline slicers. They were made just for that reason.

Timeline is useless, it shows dates that are not even in the data. Yes, I can use slicers. I guess I will do that. Thank you for your help!
